# Converting a pandas DataFrame to read file?

Tags: pandas, api, dataframe, raw-data

I've been tasked with automating access to an API of a third party vendor.

the third party vendor wants data in the format:

`data = open(fname, 'rb').read()`

yet I have data in a pandas DataFrame. What is the easiest way to go from a DataFrame to this 'data' value?

Comment: What does your output data file look like?  Is it a simple CSV?

Comment: The point is I do not want to write to a file. Writing to a file and continuing the same process is madness. I want to actually convert the DataFrame so `do_something_to(DataFrame) == open(fname, 'rb').read()` would return True here... I have to imagine writing to a csv and reading from it could be shortcut in a beautiful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a long time on this and I can literally not believe the best answer:

`csv_string = df.to_csv()`

literally just omit the filename and the output of to_csv will not write to a file. It was in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is foo, then
`foo.to_csv('filename')` will work wonders.

Comment: don't want to write to a file.